# Importing a JavaScript class into a Vue single file component using Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-mix, javascript-import

I'm writing a Vue single page component in my project which is bundled using [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix). I want to extract some logic out into its own class so that it can be easily re-used across other components (but this isn't logic that should be a Vue component itself).

I made a new class and put it in `TimeRangeConverter.js`, in the same directory as my Vue component.

```
export default class TimeRangeConverter {
    static getFromTimestamp() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And in my component, I'm importing it as I think I normally would:

```
<template>
    <div>
        Example component
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import './TimeRangeConverter';

    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log(TimeRangeConverter.getToTimestamp());
        }
    }
</script>
```

However Vue is throwing an error saying `ReferenceError: TimeRangeConverter is not defined`.

I'm using the default `webpack.mix.js` config file that comes with Laravel 5.7:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js');
```

And in my main `app.js` file I'm automatically including Vue components with:

```
const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i);
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default));
```

What's the correct way to import this class into a Vue component for usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import your class inside your component code using the following syntax :

```
 import TimeRangeConverter from './TimeRangeConverter';
```